# If I draw something, is there a tool that can translate that into javascript/canvas instructions?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to try creating shapes in javascript+canvas.. Is there a tool to transform drawings into js code ?

Comment: elaborate. drawing on the computer -> lots of context.lineTo(x, y);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way (sort of):

1. draw something using Inkscape, save as svg
2. open the svg file, find the
   definition of the shape (something
   like `M10 10L90 90`)
3. use that in the
       js framework Raphaël :
       `paper.path("M10 10L90 90");`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/).

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to have Flash you can draw in Vector format and convert to javascript and canvas using the newly released Swiffy tool from Google : http://swiffy.googlelabs.com/

Of course if you don't have Flash then that doesn't help much..

Another option could be to use DeviantART's muro web app : http://muro.deviantart.com/ . It's a drawing app made using only javascript and canvas and it looks pretty badass for a web app. I don't know if you can get the source of your drawing though, you'd have to experiment with this a bit.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, there is such online tool!**

It's called **HTML Canvas Studio**.
It allows you to draw whatever you want, the same way you do in other Paint programs.
When you finish, just export it to HTML+JS.

You can find it here: http://www.htmlcanvasstudio.com/